# running a docker image fails

Tags: javascript, selenium, docker, dockerfile, browser-automation

I am expecting to run the docker image successfully however not able to have access and getting permission denied error as below.

```
#base image
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

# Install Node.js
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash 

#Define runtime  
ENTRYPOINT /app/login.test.js
```

why is the permission denied for it?   **P.S:** I have changed to the dir which contains both Dockerfile and automation test JS files using (`cd dir`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.js` file is not an executable in itself, which is why you get permission denied.

Try running it through JavaScript:

```
ENTRYPOINT node /app/login.test.js
```

Comment: yes, I am able to run the docker image with the above command. Also, I have successfully logged into my dockerHub and pushed the image using cmd `docker tag  effead3eacdc lamgadekamal/dockertest:filetest` then `docker push lamkam/dockertest` . Did some research but not sure what next steps is it required to run a automation test in browser using the `/app/login.test.js` file and the created docker image. some ideas would be great

Comment: while running with `$ docker run -p 4000:80 lamgadekamal/dockertest` returns: 
`Unable to find image 'lamkam/dockertest:latest' locally`

docker: `Error response from daemon: manifest for lamkam/dockertest:latest not found.`  Could find why am I getting this?

Comment: You are changing the question. If my answer solved your original question then mark it as accepted, and then you can ask another Stackoverflow question and link it here.